# How to know whether MERGE "Upsert" Inserted or Updated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to MERGE - I have a MERGE statement that works:

```
merge customers with (holdlock) as c
using (select @id as id) as new_id
  on c.contactid = new_id.id
when matched then
  update set ContactID = 1, firstname = CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS VARCHAR(100))
when not matched then
  insert(ContactID) values(1), firstName = 'b';
```

(the SQL doesn't really matter - this was for testing purposes).

I've googled this but can't find the answer, I'm unclear on why no 'updated' is returned.

My question is - how could I return something indicating whether an Insert or Update happened?

Comment: you can create two columns to your table like CreatedDate and ModifiedDate. In merge when insert happens insert GetDate() in the CreatedDate column, when update occurs set ModifedDate as GetDate(). If ModifedDate column is null then it means only insert occurred and when it has value it means it get updated.

Comment: that is one option - though seems the answer below is better as it doesn't require schema changes.

Comment: I don't understand down votes on this question. The answer below requires a fairly advanced knowledge of SQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the OUTPUT clause in your merge statement with the key word $action.

Something like....

```
merge customers with (holdlock) as c
using (select @id as id) as new_id
  on c.contactid = new_id.id
when matched then
  update set ContactID = 1, firstname = CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS VARCHAR(100))
when not matched then
  insert(ContactID) values(1), firstName = 'b'

OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

The above output clause will return the action was taken in the first column like update , insert or delete and the values from inserted and deleted tables.

Comment: thanks - why "inserted.*, deleted.*" - what does that do also why no "updated.*"?

Comment: Dude.... google it http://www.made2mentor.com/2013/06/using-the-output-clause-with-t-sql-merge/

Comment: Your link doesn't actually explain what inserted.* or deleted.* does. I googled it and can find no explanation anywhere - it also appears to have no effect on my output over just OUTPUT $action.

Comment: I have since ascertained that inserted.* or deleted.* include the deleted or inserted rows in the returned output. I'm still unclear why there's no updated.*

Comment: @niico: The two SQL Server pseudo tables, inserted and deleted, are all you need to view the changes from an insert, an update or a delete.   The deleted table shows rows before they were deleted or updated.  The inserted table shows rows after they were inserted or updated.  So, for updates, the deleted table shows the state of the updated rows before the update and the inserted table shows the state of the updated rows after the update.  There is no need for an updated pseudo table.